# Consider changing StackSnippets icon image

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, stack-snippets

It just doesn't seem to match the rest of the icons in the editor:

[image]

It almost looks like an icon that was created a decade ago.  Could we use something more that signifies a script...Something more familiar such as these ?

[image]

Or even one of these:

http://www.iconarchive.com/search?q=script

**Icons displayed belong to iconarchive.com

Comment: Aww, but then I wouldn't be able to say *"Click to the icon of someone writing a postcard to add a Stack Snippet"*.

Comment: Didn't think of the postcard, to me it looked like someone was filling in a scantron test (back in the good ol days of high school).

Comment: Ya i was disappointed in my circle too...I definitely need some training in snag it :/

Comment: Have an upvote already

Comment: What is the status update on this?  Do the employees even look at these requests?

Comment: They did change what the icon looks like. It looks like they picked something similar to the 2nd and 3rd one.

Comment: OK so how do I "close" my question?

Comment: If the change was in response to this particular post, someone will answer with a short comment "fixed in the next build", like [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292021/2564301), and the post will gain a [status-completed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag. But maybe they forgot where the idea came from.