# Why does the tooltip of "show x more comments" have "... or add one of your own"?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

Here is a screenshot that shows the tooltip when I hover my cursor over the 
"*show x more comments*":

[image: SCREENSHOT]

I don't understand by there is a "*... or add one of your own*" text in the tooltip. Nobody can add comments by clicking on that link, without pressing the "*add a comment*" link.

So, why does the tooltip have that?

Comment: It's a recent change that there are separate links for adding a comment and expanding comments. Previously you had only one combined add / show link for posts with hidden comments. They probably forgot to change the tooltip in the new implementation.

Comment: You probably *should* read all the comments before adding one, though.

Comment: @Kevin , I know, and I do that. But I can't understand why there is a "...or add one of your own" in the tooltip. Hence the question.

Comment: Frankly I think we were all better off when there was one link. You should be forced to at least *expand* the comments, even if we can't verify that you read all of them, before writing one of your own. To that end, I'm fine with the tooltip technically lying to people here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, looks like the title wasn't updated during the change.

Updated now, with you in the next build.